# why a method from my subclass not working

Tags: python

Here's me playing around with `super()` method:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, width, length):

        self.width = width
        self.length = length

    def perimeter(self):

        fvalue = (self.width * 2) + (self.length * 2)

        return fvalue

    def area(self):

        fvalue = self.width * self.length

        return fvalue


class Square(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, width, length):

        super().__init__(width, length)
    
    
    def perimeter(self):

        return super().perimeter(self)

    def area(self):

        return super().area(self)


square = Square(width=3, length=3)
print(square.area())
```

now when if I run this code I will get an error that said

```
TypeError: area() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

which is weird because in `Square.area()` I've only passed 1 argument to the `super.area()` method.
I later removed that argument and the code works fine, but I'm still confused as of why this error had happened because in `Square.__init__()` I need to pass an argument for it to work. An explanation to this will be appreciated

Comment: You don't need to pass `self` when calling super methods - `super().area()`

Comment: Also apart from the init you don't need to use super() at all, I mean that's part of the point of inheritance that you're square class now also has the methods and functions of it's parent class.

Comment: And the self from the Rectangle class is probably your first parameter and the self from the square class would be the second unrequested one. Also in Square init you also don't pass the self parameter but just those required for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the methods in `Square` that duplicate the methods in the parent class. This will work fine:

```
class Rectangle:

    def __init__(self, width, length):
        self.width = width
        self.length = length

    def perimeter(self):
        fvalue = (self.width * 2) + (self.length * 2)
        return fvalue

    def area(self):
        fvalue = self.width * self.length
        return fvalue


class Square(Rectangle):

    def __init__(self, width, length):
        super().__init__(width, length)
    

square = Square(width=3, length=3)
print(square.area())
```